# Insert stored procedure passing parameter

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I have this SQL statement

```
INSERT housingSurvey ([nameID], [houseID], [jobID], [Active], [comment], [needsMaintenance], [lastUpdateDate) 
VALUES (@NAMEID, @HOUSEID, @JOBID, 1, @DUEDATE, @COMMENT, NULL, @LASTUPDATEDATE)
```

I tried this stored procedure, but I don't get the current date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE housingSurveyS(
                    @NAMEID INT,
                    @HOUSEID INT,
                    @JOBID INT, 
                    @COMMENT BIT,
                    @DUEDATE NVARCHAR,
                    CURRENTTIME)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO housingSurvey(
    [nameID],
    [houseID],
    [jobID],
    [Active],
    [comment],
    [dueDate],
    [needsMaintenance],
    [lastupdatedate])
VALUES (
    @NAMEID,
    @HOUSEID,
    @JOBID,
    1,
    @COMMENT,
    @DUEDATE,
    NULL,
    @LASTUPDATEDATE)
END
```

Could you please take a look at what I did wrong. Thanks

**UPDATE**
I changed it CURRENTTIME to DATETIME as parameter to insert current date to [lastupdatedate]... it still doesn't work...

Comment: Compare the variable order in your query. ..., also you're not using @ACTIVE but 1.

Comment: First of all - your table names are different (in your SQL INSERT and the stored proc); secondly, your stored proc wants `comment` before `dueDate`, but your list of values specifies `@DUEDATE` before `@COMMENT` ....

Comment: oh i c.. JAN... i removed that... now the currenttime is not working...

Comment: thanks marc... my order was wrong... but still can't get the currenttime

Comment: Now you're missing a comma after the `NULL` in your `VALUES(....)` list, just before `@LASTUPDATEDATE` .... BTW: SQL Server Management Studio has a `Parse` button to **parse** (and thus syntax-check!) your statement or procedure - that would catch such a silly mistake...

Comment: lol... got it... btw.. thanks the parse tip... but m still not getting the current time... should i change it to datetime...

Comment: There is a line in your procedure called `CURRENTTIME`, what is that meant to be?

Comment: Hey Peter... it is supposed to get the current date at the time of insert/update... am I doing it wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
VALUES (
    ...
    @DUEDATE,
    @COMMENT
```

Are in the wrong order when related to the order of fields defined in the `INSERT`s statements field list, switch them around.

**Edit**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE housingSurveyS(
    @NAMEID INT,
    @HOUSEID INT,
    @JOBID INT, 
    @COMMENT BIT,
    @DUEDATE NVARCHAR(32) --add a size, should this be DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO housingSurvey(
    [nameID],
    [houseID],
    [jobID],
    [Active],
    [comment],
    [dueDate],
    [needsMaintenance],
    [lastupdatedate]
) VALUES (
    @NAMEID,
    @HOUSEID,
    @JOBID,
    1,
    @COMMENT,
    @DUEDATE,
    NULL,
    GETDATE()
)
END
```

Comment: thanks Alex... i switched that... now I can't get the current time... please take a look at my update code..

Comment: So you dont pass in a datetime? - remove `,CURRENTTIME` that's not valid t-sql and insert `getdate()` instead of `@LASTUPDATEDATE` which you don't declare/define anywhere anyway

Comment: No Alex... in my controller, I use the current time/date when it's inserted/updated...

Comment: Updated, I don't know about your "controller" but CURRENTTIME is incorrect